# Corona tabbar rendering precision

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to build a tabbar in corona only using custom graphics for up/down states, and background. I find that corona adds left and right padding as the attached image & basic setup  below shows. The images are both 32x32 and should fill the space exactly, instead there are black lines at either end and the buttons are forced to overlap.

I've tried every option available in the docs but with no success. Does anyone know if there's an undocumented option that overrides the automatic positioning of tabbar buttons?

```
    -- table to setup buttons
    local tabButtons = {
        { up="icon1.png", down="icon1-down.png", width = 32, height = 32, cornerRadius=0, onPress=onFirstView, selected=true },
        { up="icon2.png", down="icon2-down.png", width = 32, height = 32, cornerRadius=0, onPress=onSecondView },
    }

    -- create the actual tabBar widget
    local tabBar = widget.newTabBar{
        width=64, height=32,
        buttons = tabButtons
    }
```

Here's the output:

[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug and is being addressed.

Comment: Thanks, I did check the corona buglist on FogBugz, but couldn't find anything. That said, search didn't work for me at all and I was unable to view details of any individual case.

Comment: Just heard from corona: "The team are working on remaking scrollViews, tableViews & pickerWheels, tabBars etc from scratch with the new widget framework."